# IONIC2 - SyntaxError: docs/file.js: Unexpected token (13:22) while parsing file: docs/file.js

Tags: angular, ionic2, swiper.js

I am importing a component called [Swiper-Angular2](https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular2-swiper-example) into my IONIC 2 project, but I am receiving a weird error that says:

> SyntaxError: docs/file.js: Unexpected token (13:22) while parsing file: docs/file.js

So far, my code is:

page.js

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Example1} from '../swiper/swiper';


@Page({ 
templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
directives: [Example1]
})
export class HomePage {}
```

page.html

```
<ion-content>
<example1><example1>
</ion-content>
```

swiper.js

```
import {Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {KSSwiperContainer, KSSwiperSlide} from 'angular2-swiper';

@Component({
selector: 'example1',
pipes: [],
providers: [],
directives: [KSSwiperContainer, KSSwiperSlide],
template: require('./swiper.html')
})
//The error triggers here, exactly after "Example1"
export class Example1 implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild(KSSwiperContainer) swiperContainer: KSSwiperContainer;

example1SwipeOptions: any;

constructor() {
this.example1SwipeOptions = {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  loop: false,
  spaceBetween: 5
};
}

moveNext() {
this.swiperContainer.swiper.slideNext();
}

movePrev() {
this.swiperContainer.swiper.slidePrev();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log(this.swiperContainer);
}

}
```

Swiper.html

```
<div class="myslides">
<ks-swiper-container [options]="example1SwipeOptions">
<ks-swiper-slide *ngFor="#s of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
<img src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/thumb/men/{{s}}.jpg">
</ks-swiper-slide>
</ks-swiper-container>
<button (click)="movePrev()">Prev</button>
<button (click)="moveNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Any ideas on what's causing the problem?

Comment: Do you use ES6 into your Ionic2 project?

Comment: What is the content of this file: `docs/file.js`? Thanks!

Comment: ES6 is already there, I can see it clearly in app.js. 
file.js == swiper.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/insert-swiper-slides-per-view-carousel-mode/50355

I believe yo don't even need to import Swiper; however, you can simply use it as it is already build-in in IONIC2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've just followed the steps on the link you provided and I've solved my issue!